# filling dynamically allocated struct inside function

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to make a function that accepts a pre-allocated memory pointer as input and fills an array of structs at that location with data. In this example, I expected the output to be:

```
W 100
L 200
```

However, the first line is correct, but the second line prints no character and a zero. What am I doing wrong?

```
typedef struct{
  char word;
  long number;
}record;

void makerec(record** data){
  data[0]->word='W';
  data[0]->number=100;
  data[1]->word='L';
  data[1]->number=200;
}

int main(){
  record* data=(record*)malloc(sizeof(record)*1000);
  makerec(&data);
  printf("%c %ld\n",data[0].word,data[0].number);
  printf("%c %ld\n",data[1].word,data[1].number);
  free(data);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `data[1]` accesses out of bounds. You mean `(*data)[1].word='L';` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not dealing with the right types. Simply change:

```
void makerec(record** data) {
```

to:

```
void makerec(record * data) {
```

and:

```
makerec(&data);
```

to:

```
makerec(data);
```

as well as changing `data[0]->word='W';` and friends to `data[0].word = 'W';`

`data` is already a pointer, and you want to change the thing to which it points, so you can just pass it directly to `makerec`. You'd pass a pointer to `data` if you wanted `makerec()` to make it point to something different, but that's not what you're doing here, so just passing `data` itself is correct.

Incidental to your main issue, but:

```
record* data=(record*)malloc(sizeof(record)*1000);
```

should be:

```
record* data = malloc(1000 * sizeof *data);
if ( !data ) {
    perror("memory allocation failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Notes:

1. You don't need to (and, to my mind, shouldn't) cast the return value of `malloc()` and friends
2. `sizeof *data` is better than `sizeof(record)`, since it continues to work if the type of `data` changes, and more importantly, it removes the possibility of you applying the `sizeof` operator to an incorrect type, which is a common mistake.
3. Reversing the positions of `1000` and `sizeof *data` is merely cosmetic, to make the multiple `'*'`s easier to comprehend.
4. You should always check the return value of `malloc()` in case the allocation failed, and take appropriate action (such as exiting your program) if it did.